# processor don't go idle its 60-100% with nothing on

Tags: cpu, process, idle

I have an Acer Aspire v3 - i7 processor which is normally on windows with nothing on or browsing like 10-20% busy , just installed ubuntu 15 on that labtop it keep process at 60-100% with nothing running or just terminal updating-upgrading and firefox -with system monitor i have seen its like 5% for every one of those so it should be max 20% busy !

it burn the cpu to hell everything became slow i had to trurn it off.

have seen older question same thing but nothing useful on it to fix this.
btw have 2 desktops running ubuntu i7 and Amd x4 they both fine with ubuntu 15.

thanx in advance.

---edit screenshots today
i ran and sudo apt-get update and upgrade
it was fine and idle for a while then it happened again
it started when it was idle btw but i can't upldoad more than 2 links

screenshots

[with chrome download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2sA3.png)
[with chrome download2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LiJP.png)

i had to trun it off , too hot and was extremly slow cause of that.

Comment: What is the output of `top` command?  You may be able to see the culprit there.

Comment: which i7 processor is it?  What graphics does it have? What does command 'uname -r" say?

Comment: Did you run ubuntu as a virtual machine or dual boot ?   my guess is you ran it as a virtual machine probably RAM constrained ... if you install ubuntu as a dual boot it runs stand alone not as a child process of MS Windows so its resource usage benefits will be evident

Comment: -top process was the system monitor itself only 5% or something and others is 3% and something , thats whats wierd

Comment: its Aspire V3 571G with GT 630m card included

Comment: its a dual boot with win 8 on 20GB drive and 2 gb swap
although i have to go to bois setup change settings from uefi bios to legacy to have the ubuntu login not win 8.

Comment: i7 3632QM 2.2GHz

Comment: what do you get for `grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo` , when you have this situation?

Comment: sorry i'm kindof noob , I did upload sceenshots off system monitor 
idk codes for those in terminal .